# How to properly add interfaces as constructor parameters?

Tags: java, lambda

I have initialized this Game() constructor in my main method that takes 2 interfaces as parameters:

```
    Game game = new Game(
            (player, bridge) -> {
                if (player instanceof HumanPlayer)
                    return true;
                if (player instanceof RobotPlayer && bridge instanceof FakeBridge)
                    return true;
                return false;
            },
            (player) -> {
                if (player instanceof HumanPlayer) {
                    HumanPlayer hPlayer = (HumanPlayer) player;
                    hPlayer.updateAge(hPlayer.age() + 1);
                    Car car = (Car) hPlayer.vehicle();
                    car.setGas(car.gas());
                } else if (player instanceof RobotPlayer) {
                    RobotPlayer rPlayer = (RobotPlayer) player;
                    rPlayer.updatePower(rPlayer.power() - 5);
                }
                System.out.println(player);
            }
        );
```

Here are the two interfaces I provided inside the constructor for Game()

```
public Initialize initial;
public Interface2 player1;
```

And here is the constructor for the Game class:

```
 public Game(Initialize initial, Interface2 player ) {
     this.initial = initial;
     this.player = player1;
 }
```

With that it is still giving me an error for some reason:
**The constructor Game(( player,  bridge) -> {}, ( player) -> 
 {}) is undefined**

EDIT: Here are the two interfaces I provided:

```
public interface Initialize {
    boolean constraint(Player player, Bridge bridge);
}
```

and

```
public interface Interface2 {
    public boolean constraint2(Player player);
}
```

Comment: please show the interface definitions.

Comment: i've added them to the post

Comment: Two interfaces with the same name?

Comment: my bad! I fixed it...

Comment: You're missing a return statement for the function `(player) -> {...}` but if you don't want to return a value then use the `Consumer` interface.

Comment: That said, you should use `BiPrediate` and/or `Predicate`/`Consumer` instead of creating your own interfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a return statement for the function `(player) -> {...}` but if you don't want to return a value then use the [Consumer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html) interface.

That said, I'd recommend using the [interfaces already in place](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) instead of creating your own exact copy of them.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is about the second declaration the signature didn't match to the interface : this compile :

```
public void run() {
    Game game = new Game((player, bridge) -> {
        return true;
    }, (player) -> {
        return true;
    });
}

public class Bridge {

}

public class Player {

}

public interface Initialize {
    boolean constraint(Player player, Bridge bridge);
}

public interface Interface2 {
    boolean constraint(Player player);
}

public class Game {
    private Initialize initial;
    private Interface2 player;

    public Game(Initialize initial, Interface2 player) {
        this.initial = initial;
        this.player = player;
    }
}
```

your missing to have a return type on your second declaration